# Why angular 11 doesn't import and show correctly styles in my application?

Tags: angular, import, routes, styles

i have different components in my app and root's folder is src with a subfolder named styles. My problem is that i have 2 components with this scss:

```
@import 'src/styles/custom.scss'; // this contain: @mixin test { color: red; }
.myClassCustom{
    @include test();
}
```

This two components have same scss code that is apply in the same way, but if i open my app, first component that is showed work correctly and show color style, while second component that is in another Route shows style only if i use a routing's navigate. Otherwise if i navigate directly with url second component doesn't show color and i don't found the compiled css dependent from @import and @include operations. What could be the problem?

Comment: Is there any ViewEncapsulation applied on any of these components?
Also, whats the behavior when you put these css in a global file, like styles.scss?

Comment: yes, in the first component i have encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None in @Component annotation, and if i put encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None in the second component it works. But why does this happen?

Comment: are these components part of same module?

Comment: I created this stackblitz, can you verify the structure? like are your components in the same hierarchy? you can make chanegs if you want to.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-view-encapsulation-fu1yrm?file=app%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html